# How do I find the gender of person from his/her occupation in python

Tags: python, text, nlp, text-processing

I am a pet project where i'm investigating that women in asia are mostly depicted as doing labor or house hold jobs while men are mostly doing more respectable jobs like doctor, surgeon, professor etc.

I am working on a python script which given a sentence would estimate the gender for the occupation found in the given piece of text.

**E.g:**
The patient consulted the doctor for treatment, He knows his stuff very well and cured lots of patients in the past.
We can see that the doctor is clearly a male here. That's what I wanna do. Find the gender of person doing the occupation from text.

**What have i done:**
I thought of counting the male words/pronouns such as he / she / his / her and then counting their total to see who has got more frequency to estimate the gender.

**What's the problem:**
The approach i'm using is not a good estimator of the problem.

**E.g:**

He asked the doctor to treat him as she has treated him the past. Here in this example, the male words are more in number (He, him, him) than the female words (she) while clearly the doctor is female.

**What i'm looking for?**
I'm looking for more intelligent ideas from this kaggle community to help me progress on this problem. Any leads big or small would be really appreicated.

Comment: That's an amazing problem I would love to see the implementation too.

Comment: Great to hear that, could you please upvote it to get more attention.

Comment: have you considered using any natural language toolkit? I think identifying various part of speech in the sentence will help a little.

Comment: I considered using nltk, but couldn't find anything to make use of. I found one gender classifier but it was only for names. @K450, do you know any toolkit i should made use of, i'd love to try out.

Comment: i was thinking of nltk as well. But you can try spacy. And dont look for gender classifiers, instead look for reference resolution, as you want to resolve what pronoun refers to which noun across one or multiple sentences.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll try it out

Answer (score 1):

**You can use *Stanford OpenIE***.

You can **count number of subjects** from **output given by OpenIE** and **their relation to occupation(noun).**

**Output the gender of subject, the subject which is related to occupation.**

Here is an example Sentence dependency:

[image]

Comment: your image is not related to the question. you could show instead the library in action with the two example sentences of the question

Comment: Nice insights, i'll go ahead and give this a try